# jquery adjust table row value by one less than current value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that gets items added and deleted to it. Once an Item is deleted I want all of the table index items greater than the deleted one to decrease by one. If I want to change the text off all the rows greater than the one deleted I could do.

```
   $("#quote tbody tr:gt("+rownumber+")").find('.item_num').text("CHANGE TO THIS TEXT");
```

The value I want to change is a number, How can I change it to be one less than it's current value? Thank you

Comment: what is a table index item? is it a td, a tr, .. ? some html on jsfiddle would be nice

Comment: I create a row that is just numbered items, 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop:

```
$("#quote tbody tr:gt("+rownumber+")").find('.item_num').text(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) - 1;
});
```

#### [Here's a simple example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uAAGj/2/)

Answer (score 2):

It's a little more complex, so you'll need to loop through the elements explicitly instead of implicitly to find the current value and then increment it.

```
$("#quote tbody tr:gt("+rownumber+")").each(function(i, el) {
    var $item_num = $(el).find('.item_num');
    $item_num.text(parseInt($item_num.text())-1);
});
```

Comment: that looks good to me, but it does not work. I am putting that code above in a function and passing rownumber as a parameter to it. are you sure it works if so is there anything else I would need to do because I am calling it inside another function?